how can you open a linux app and pass a file from a wine app
Using Debian 12_x64, [wine 9 Running 64 bit Irfanviw] I want to open a linux 64bit app (e.g krita) and pass an image (e.g. anyimage.png) to the linux 64 bit app. using the Irvanview "open with external editor" from the Irfanview file menu.
SUCESSFULLY TESTED opening a 64 bit (pixia.exe) app with an image file running in wine, with Irfanview.exe also running in wine using "open with external editor" I have been unable to find any documentation on how to do the same thing with a linux external editor.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Have you consider to change the windows app, for example XnView MP have native Linux version?

One minor nuisance is that wine apps use a different directory structure, e.g., Z: for /home. One can edit arguments passed, e.g., adding a folder to command line. Of course, it takes only a second longer to save the file from IrfanView and open in Krita.

If you have a shared directory between the host and VM, it should be pretty simple.  Put the image in the shared folder and use krita /path/to/share/image.png  Your question is kind of vague...
